# How do I limit the number of auto-restarts on pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a node server running on pm2 which depends on some external services.

When those servers go down I pm2 starts restarting my app, but this will keep going until it clogs up my cpu and ram on the server, restarting as much as 50 times a minute.

Is there a way to limit the numbers of restarts on pm2? There is a way to restart the server when the server reaches a certain RAM memory level, so I would hope this feature I am asking for exists.

Comment: "restart the server when the server reaches a certain RAM memory level" this would be a very very bad way to deal with memory leaks... Not sure why you want to do this.

Answer (score 13):

You can use combination of `max_restarts` and `min_uptime` to restrict the app to restart consecutively.

> number of consecutive unstable restarts (less than 1sec interval or custom time via min_uptime) before your app is considered errored and stop being restarted

More information about `max_restarts` and `min_uptime` is available [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#yaml-format)

Answer (score 5):

Use PM2 ecosystem.config.js file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "app",
    script: "./app.js",
    merge_logs: true,
    max_restarts": 50, //Here you can define your max restarts
    instances: "max",
    max_memory_restart: "200M",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }]
}
```

Start your server by following command:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js //uses variables from `env`
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production //uses variables from `env_production`
```

For more details see below link:

[PM2 Runtime | Guide | Ecosystem File](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/ecosystem-file/)

Answer (score 3):

Options for config file if you have: `ecosystem.config.js`

```
{
    watch_delay: 5000,

    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 100,

    restart_delay: 1000,
    max_restarts: 2,
    min_uptime: 5000,
    autorestart: false,
}
```

Otherwise, give the same command line, as below:

```
pm2 start app.js --restart-delay=3000
pm2 start app.js --no-autorestart
```

They themselves know the issue, so see the 1st link below:

- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/
- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/

Mine got fixed only after `watch_delay: 5000,` and nothing else was required.