# pm2 --max-restarts limit not working and continuous restarting crash host system

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I tried pm2 to restrict restart limit with `--max-restarts` but it's not working and also tired `min_uptime`

```
sudo pm2 start server.js --max-restarts=5
```

And I also tried with `yml` file

```
apps:
  - name: node-mt
    script: server-socket.js
    watch: true
    max_restarts: 5
    min_uptime: 5000
```

But it's not limiting restart of the application.

**If pm2 crashes regularly it crashed the host system and memory usage reached from 300mb to 800mb.**

Its normal state when app running.

[image]

**When an application crashes. Then graph goes very high.**

I need to stop max restart to avoid crashing host due to high usage of memory. I don't want to restrict memory usage flag.
[image]

Comment: I had watch files `on` so below dint work. See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302296/984471

Answer (score 17):

PM2 `max_restarts` ane `min_uptime` works perfectly fine. You need to understand the analogy of both.

As per documentation

> number of consecutive unstable restarts (less than 1sec(default)
>   interval or custom time via min_uptime) before your app is considered
>   errored and stop being restarted

This means that if your min_uptime is 5000 and max_restarts is 5 then your app will be considered errored if the app is crashed and restarted 5 time in less than 5000ms. If it restarts 4 times in 5 second than it will not consider it as errored and continue restarting it.

**If your app keeps restarting with this config that means your app is not restarting 5 times in 5 second. The possible solution is give a relatively high number in min_uptime like an hour or so for your case or you can find it by manual test.**

I have a good time understanding this when I first encountered it with my node cron app and created following demo.

**app.js**

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('killed');
  process.exit(1)
}, 100);
```

**ecosystem.config.json**

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"         : "api",
    "script"       : "./app.js",
    "max_restarts" : 3,
    "min_uptime"   : 300
  }]
}
```

This will kill your process but if you change the timeout to 130+(I don't know why but it works for the values less than 130 as may be ms pricision and not considering config till 1st restart) then it won't work. It will start restarting the app.

[PM2 documnetation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)

**P.S.**

`min_uptime` can be given in string too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response let me try it

Comment: If you go through impmention of pm2 there is only tag --max-restart in pm2 github project not any implementation there is only  in readme you can check https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: @Adiii haev you tried running manually and see when app crashes. As this works pretty fine. It's just your restart time and crash times are mismatching. You can run the example I have provided to understand the process

Comment: can we provide a running example wit express app pls

Comment: You can create one by throwing an unhandled error after express initializes with settimeout and monitor the pm2 logs.

Comment: lets discuss in chat i added u